# Export from Excel to a word Document and insert a header in word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code:

```
    Sub CreateRapport()

    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wd As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

    wdApp.Visible = True



Sheets("Rapport").Activate
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E76")

Rng.Copy

   With wd.Range
        .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .InsertParagraphAfter                   'Lägg till rad
        .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .PasteSpecial False, False, True        'Pasta som Enhanced Metafile

    End With

End Sub
```

What it does is that it creates a word document with the data from range A1:E76

I want to insert a header in this word document that contains a picture and a name. The name in this header is in cell A1 in the same sheet.

Would be very thankful if anyone could help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to add text from cell A1 to the document:

```
wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text
```

How to turn the current text into a header:

```
'***** Word VBA constant wdStyleHeading1 = -2
wdApp.Selection.Style = -2
```

How to add an image:

```
wdApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:="PATH_TO_IMAGE", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
```

If you put the above code together and add it directly after the line `wdApp.Visible = True` you will get a header with an image at the end, but I can't tell from your question exactly how you want the document to look.

**EDIT**

Code to show current header:

```
'***** Word VBA constant wdSeekCurrentPageHeader = 9
wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
```

Show normal view:

```
'***** Word VBA constant wdSeekMainDocument  = 0
wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0
```

Putting it all together, paste this after the line `wdApp.Visible = True`, this time without setting the style:

```
wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text
wdApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:="PATH_TO_IMAGE", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0
```

**EDIT 2**

My suggestion about transferring the embedded image from Excel to Word is to use copy and paste:

```
'***** copy image from cell B1 in Excel
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Copy
'***** past image at the current position in Word
wdApp.Selection.Paste
```

The code needs to go somewhere near the `wdApp.Selection.TypeText` command, depending on where you want the image to display.

**EDIT 3**

Code for adding page number field:

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

Comment: Hej Olle! I have tried to paste in the code directly under wdApp.Visible = True as you said but it appeared a "heading"-text in the document. What if I want to add a text inside the "header of the document". Also the path_to_image, is within the same sheet as the the header text, A1.

Comment: `"PATH_TO_IMAGE"` is meant to be a path to the harddrive on the client running Excel (eg "C:\temp\image.jpg"). Is the image embedded in the excel sheet?

Comment: Yes, the image is embedded in the Excel Sheet.

Comment: How can I insert an embedded picture and also insert the cell A1 inside of the "header of the document" instead of just as a header in the document? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh, you mean write text in the header of the document? Sorry, I did not understand. Basically, you do it the same way, only you need to tell Word to enter the text and/or image in the header instead. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, thank you very much. I'll try the new code when you do :)

Comment: Done! Still not sure about the embedded picture, though. You need to get the picture object in Excel and see if you can copy it to a similar object in Word. See if you can identify where in the Excel object model you can find it, probably in the `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Pictures` collection.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked fine, grymt jobbat! By the way, in cell A1 i have a "=NOW()" -function which generates time. How can I get it to do it automaticly when you run the macro above? And also how can I insert page number in the bottom of the page :)? I will try figure it out with the pictue. Thanks for your patience and time mister.

Comment: Bra att det funkar! Page number is a field in Word and can be added in code. General tip: record a macro of what you want to do and see the generated code, works in both Word and Excel. It gave me the code for the page number in edit #3. :)

Comment: PS. If the answer was helpful, you can close the question by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. :) By the way, your question really consists of several questions which should probably have been asked separately.

Comment: Ah ok I see! Thank you. By the way if I want the A1 range to be A1:C3, how can I make that work :)?